# Send a third-party API request when Case is created

Tags: post, business-catalyst

I know in the "Settings > API Integration" I can add a URL that will receive a POST when a Case (Customer Inquiry) is created, however the contents of that POST only contains two IDs e.g. `ObjectID=1234567&ObjectType=2001`

Is there a way that I can send a custom POST to some URL with the actual form data? E.g. if I wanted to send the person who submitted the form a text message via a third-party SMS API

Answer (score 0):

No; you'll need to respond to that `POST` with one that extracts the data you need from BC, then transform & forward that data to the SMS service.

This implies that you'll have a third server to handle those intermediary steps.

---

http://docs.businesscatalyst.com/reference/soap-apis-legacy/crm/case_retrieve.html

Answer (score 0):

Another approach to do this is to write some ajax post function to post form data to the desired URL before submission.