# Get Cases in Business Catalyst REST API

Tags: rest, api, soap, business-catalyst

Business Catalyst has a push notification for new customer inquiries that sends a POST request with the object ID, e.g.`ObjectID=1234567&ObjectType=2001`

The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37821583/send-a-third-party-api-request-when-case-is-created) say to use the SOAP API(Legacy) to request the details of the case.

Is there a way to do this using the new Rest API?https://docs.worldsecuresystems.com/reference/rest-apis/index.html

There is no documented method for a *cases* or *case* endpoint.

If not, the only solution wil be to mix the API calls being used .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of the API's haven't been updated to v3 yet (REST) so unfortunately you will still need to use the SOAP endpoint for the Cases API.

Comment: Thanks! That was confirmed by BC too.